# How to add a space in action of an intent filter of a activity In Android Manifest File

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, android-manifest

I am using the following code to open an activity on click of a Notification from the notification bar.

```
<activity android:name=".controllers.activities.myactivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.mypackage.MYAppName.NOTIFICATION" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

My question is how to put a space in the App name. When i am trying to put the space directly its giving me an error saying space is not accepted.

```
EX:- <action android:name="com.mypackage.MY App Name.NOTIFICATION" />
```

I am using IBM Mobilefirst sdk for push. So Mobilefirst document says I have to do it this way. I need to get it this issue resolved by

- Either I have to find a way to put a space in the action (android:name) of Intent filter
- IBM Mobilefirst should have a different way to do this.

Can some help me handling this issue.

Comment: "I cant skip the space" -- why not? More to the point, why is this `<intent-filter>` there in the first place?

Comment: I am working on Ibm Mobilefirst with native android and its asking me to do so... i cant change my broadcast receiver and service code. On click of notification this is the code which is bringing my app to foreground.

Comment: You do not need an `<intent-filter>` for this, unless IBM screwed something up. You only need an `<intent-filter>` if *some other app* is going to be using an `Intent` to try to start this activity. For a `Notification`, use an explicit `Intent` (e.g., `new Intent(this, myactivity.class)`) and eliminate the `<intent-filter>`.

Comment: I would be able to do that if i have access to the broadcast receiver. Receiver code is part of IBM's SDK.

Comment: So, IBM screwed up. Where is IBM's SDK coming up with this action string? Why is it trying to create an action string with spaces in it?

Comment: The actual point is they want me to key the value as android:name=packagename.Appname.NOTIFICATION .Now my app name has spaces. Is there a way?

Comment: Get rid of the spaces from the app name. Or, find a way to tell IBM's SDK to use something else for the action string. Or, ignore the Lint warning, see if your app works, and if it does, pray that nothing in Android changes that more strictly enforces this no-spaces requirement.

Comment: How to do ignore lint warnings specific to manifest file.

Comment: Put your text cursor in the error, and press `<Alt>-<Enter>` (or the equivalent for a Mac) to bring up the quick fixes. There should be some options in there, such as "add `tools:ignore`".

Comment: @Bender, did you try the way to ignore the warnings?

Comment: It dint work Idan.. The only work around i did was, creating two different values in String.xml which is app-name and app-label. app-label value I have assigned it to the label in manifest and used app-name for the above mentioned thing. Here the app label had a value with spaces its the actual app name we see under app icon in our phone . And the app-name is some text without spaces which could be used for our Notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cant keep a space in action value of intent filter.